# What are the meanings of the terms "Passed" and "Approved" with regards to a movie title?

Tags: terminology, imdb

On IMDb there are various movies which bear the words "Passed" or "Approved" next to their title, as e.g. seen on [this page.](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0024679/?ref_=ttrel_rel_tt) or [this one](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0043975/). In addition, at least [one movie's page](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0057434/?ref_=fn_tt_tt_1) features *neither* of said two terms.

What do these terms mean with regards to those films? Are they just irrelevant IMDb-specific terms or are they general film-industry terminology? In the latter case, what are they referring to?

Comment: Can you post a link to an entry with this term on it?

Comment: I'm somewhat dubious about whether this is on topic or not - we're not IMDB support or FAQ.  An example wouldn't hurt to provide either, I don't recall seeing one of these.

Comment: @iandotkelly - I tend to agree.  I mean, I don't mind answering it if I can figure it out once an example is provided, but it's definitely not within the scope of this site and probably should be closed.

Comment: Linked example added to the question.

Comment: Perhaps it is about the content of that page that tells it is either approved or passed. I can give details.

Comment: Yet another linked example added to the question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the working of a website.

Comment: @AJ I disagree...it's about a "rating" applied to the movie. There is no indication that this rating was **applied by the IMDB site**. They are merely recording what rating was applied....unless you have information to the contrary.

Comment: Um, *where* exactly are those terms supposed to be shown?

Comment: @Paulie_D Are you sure that it is about a "rating" applied to the movie while the meta itemprop shows contentRating? You're a programmer too. Check this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/7m9YV.png

Comment: @NapoleonWilson, the terms in question appear directly below the movie's title, on the far left...

Comment: Not for me, though.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson, I've verified the stated behavior using two different browsers (Firefox and Chrome).  Suggest you check for the subject terms, using the _first two_ links in the original question (note that the _third_ link in said question will yield an example where neither of the two subject terms appears).  Look directly below the movie's title, at the far left...

Comment: Interesting.  Based on the answer, I'd say this is a legit (and good) question.

Comment: Like @NapoleonWilson I don't see it. Under the title it only shows me "Running time", "Genre" and "Release Date". - Maybe it's a IMDbPro thing, or it's country specific (I'm in Europe).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The text under an IMDb title lists some of the movie’s characteristics: **Certificate (rating)**, runtime, genre, and release date.

[**Certificate**](http://www.imdb.com/glossary/C) is IMDb-speak for a movie’s rating. In addition, if you scroll down to the bottom of the Storyline section of a [typical movie’s listing](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0067927/) (arbitrarily chosen), you will see its articulated MPAA rating along with a link to view its corresponding rating in other countries (please also see [IMDb ratings of other countries](https://contribute.imdb.com/updates/guide/certificates)).

So why have “Passed”, “Accepted”, or nothing? The familiar MPAA ratings (G, PG, etc) were not around for the selections you are questioning.

[The Motion Picture Production Code](http://www.asu.edu/courses/fms200s/total-readings/MotionPictureProductionCode.pdf), dated March 31, 1930, (aka The Hayes Code) was intended to be a set of rules to govern American filmmaking. This extract describing the code indicates that there was [essentially only one rating](https://www.und.edu/instruct/cjacobs/ProductionCode.htm): Approved. Its absence would mean not approved:

> Films were not rated for different ages by the Production Code Administration. They were **either approved by the Code for release or not**, and the major studios would not release a film without the Code’s seal of approval. In the 1950s a few filmmakers and distributors started to defy the code (especially with foreign imports), and by the 1960s many of the code’s restrictions were loosened if a film’s advertising carried a notice recommending it for mature audiences. [Emphasis mine]

But the Code did not prove to be effective. This extract from [Filmmaker IQ](http://filmmakeriq.com/lessons/the-history-of-hollywood-censorship-and-the-ratings-system/) describes it pretty well and what happened next:

> In March 31, 1930, the MPPDA issued a statement of policy called the The Motion Picture Production Code (also known as the Hays Code). It set up a small jury to review films for content, Understaffed and headed by ineffectual but mostly uninterested board members, the Hays Code was still without teeth and largely mocked by industry insiders.
>
> That changed when the American Bishops of the Roman Catholic Church organized The Legion of Decency and in 1934 with the support of Protestant and Jewish Organizations began calling for boycotts of films deemed unacceptable.
>
> This was the dollar that broke the camel’s back – The Hollywood studios, still reeling from the losses of 1933 due in large part to the delayed effects of the Great Depression, were forced to act.

So in 1934, financial and religious pressure started to make these ratings relevant. In my estimation, this may be the difference between the terms “Passed” and “Approved” as used by IMDb. Again, this is only a guess on my part. But it does seem clear that “Approved” refers directly to the Code.

So how does my theory play out? I more or less randomly chose five movies from the years 1933, 1934, and 1935. Here is what I observed. Please note that *Tomorrow at Seven* is from 1933, and *Roaring City* is from 1951.

Some movie selections from 1933 seem to indicate the prevalence of “Passed”:

- [*Ace of Aces*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0023737/) Shows “Passed”.
- [*Ann Vickers*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0023759/) Shows “Passed”.
- [*Bed of Roses*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0023786/) Shows “Passed”.
- [*The Constant Woman*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0023904/) Shows “Passed”.
- [*The Crime of the Century*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0023918/) Shows “Passed”.

Some movie selections from 1934 seem to indicate transition (1 apparently not rated):

- [*The Beast of Borneo*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0025075/) Shows nothing.
- [*Belle of the Nineties*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0024873/) Shows “Approved”.
- [*By Your Leave*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0024939/) Shows “Approved”.
- [*Death on the Diamond*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0025039/) Shows “Passed”.
- [*The Ghost Walks*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0025169/) Shows “Passed”.

Some movie selections from 1935 seem to indicate the prevalence of “Approved” (1 Not Rated):

- [*The Arizonian*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0026082/) Shows “Approved”.
- [*Bride of Frankenstein*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0026138/) Shows “Not Rated”.
- [*Call of the Wild*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0026164/) Shows “Approved”.
- [*Condemned to Live*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0026230/) Shows “Approved”.
- [*Gigolette*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0026408/) Shows “Approved”.

The question example of the unrated film shows that it’s from Denmark. I inspected a number of films from Denmark and noticed that none of them are rated (no rating or “Unrated” or “Not Rated”). I don’t know exactly what this means, but it appears to be common for films from Denmark -- even though there are IMDb equivalent ratings listed for Denmark.

Answer (score 4):

**well well well**, here we have the lesser-spotted-looks-off-topic-but-actually-contains-a-charming-factoid....

Before certification boards such as the MPAA and BBFC (which contained various levels of certification pertaining to different audiences), there were only two types of classification in Cinematic exhibition:

**Pass** or Deny

Comment: A reference link to confirm this would enhance this answer no end. Perhaps https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_Picture_Production_Code

Comment: What about the terms "Passed" and "Approved" then? Approved for review, passed the review?